# [python]: problem about passing map() with a func and 2 lists with different dimensions

Tags: python, dictionary

suppose I got a list, say

```
lst1 = [1,2,3,4]
```

and another list, say

```
lst2 = [8,9]
```

and a func, say

```
func = lambda x,y: x+y
```

what I want to do is to produce a list whose element is the sum of lst1's element and lst2's.
i.e., I want to produce a lst with lst1 and lst2, and lst should be

```
[1+8+9, 2+8+9, 3+8+9, 4+8+9].
```

how can I do it with map()?

Comment: Why would you do it with `map()`?

Comment: @Synapse:  what does your `func` have to do with anything here?  Is it supposed to be used somewhere?

Comment: @Gerrat:No, by func I just want to demonstrate my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> map(lambda x: x + sum(lst2), lst1)
[18, 19, 20, 21]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> map(lambda x, y: x + y, lst1, itertools.repeat(sum(lst2), len(lst1)))
[18, 19, 20, 21]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your func is simply add operator so you can use 'add' from operator module the following way:

```
from operator import add
lst = [1,2,3,4]
sLst = [8,9]
map(lambda x: add(x, sum(sLst)), lst)
>>> [18,19,20,21]
```

It is ok to use map - but usually it is not so fast as simple list comprehension that also looks pretty clear:

```
from operator import add
lst = [1,2,3,4]
sLst = [8,9]
[add(x, sum(sLst)) for x in lst]
>>> [18,19,20,21]
```